# Proof that $A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof

I'm trying to prove $A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$. I've seen several proofs for this which all seemed to essentially go about proving it by noticing that $\emptyset\subset A\cap\emptyset$ by definition and then supposing some x in $A\cap\emptyset$ and then saying that this is a subset of $\emptyset$.I see the logic here and Im certainly not saying it's wrong obviously but I feel like there's certain logical gaps there. So, I went about trying to do it differently and I came up with the following but was wondering if this is correct since I haven't been able to find it elsewhere, and, if it is correct, why this convention isn't more often used

> Suppose $x\in \emptyset\cap A$
>   ,thus $x\in A$ and $x\in\emptyset$.
>   By definition, $x$ cannot belong to $\emptyset$
>   , thus there is no $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\in A\cap\emptyset$
>   , hence $\emptyset\cap A=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is correct. Another way to say it:
$A\cap\emptyset\subset\emptyset$ (property of intersection). And the only subset of $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$. So $A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$.

Comment: This is a very intuitive way of approaching the problem in my opinion.